# Add a simple process in a account.invoice workflow

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, workflow-activity

I want to add a small process after an user validate an invoice in Openerp 7 (just some recording for the salesperson) but i dont know how to 'intercept' the action ?

Comment: save some additional data after an invoice has been validated

Comment: if you want do something more when validating invoice you can write your code in function "invoice_validate".

Comment: it is impossible to modify openerp's code , i have to creeate a new module

Comment: why you said impossible to modify openerp's code? It is very easy to modify in openerp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just had to inherit the `account_invoice` class and define a new `invoice_validate` method

@user1576199 is this what you meant ?

```
from account import account_invoice

class account_invoice(osv.osv):
    _inherit="account.invoice"
    def invoice_validate(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        super(account_invoice,self).invoice_validate()
```